# What's the easiest way to setup and mirror 2 React.js components

Tags: reactjs, components

I wanna create two components, each of them reflecting a page, a view but with same state and props. Let me go deeper into this:

What I want to achieve is have two pages, each consisting of a React component, with both components having the same state and render. 
Like a mirror if I may. The page should take an input into a field and should render that input's value (I managed to do so) but when I change the value, the changes should also be reflected on the other page. 
And the other (second) page, while reflecting that value, can also manipulate the same input field.

Basically a field with 2 controllers from 2 distinct pages controlling the same value. I've created the components and I'm also using Redux. I can successfully change the initial state (value) and get the new state via store but changes are not reflected in the second component. How do I do that? I'm pretty new to both React and Redux and I know I should not dive into Redux while still a React noob.

Comment: When you talk about two "pages", you mean like browser tabs or what?

Comment: Yes. config.html and secondconfig.html. Both opened at the same time in two tabs, correct.

Comment: You might think to work with Redux actions, saving in the localStorage on each edit and poll for changes. Interesting challenge :)

Comment: I actually forgot about that entirely! I did it and it worked like a charm. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

I've created a persistedState within my store:

```
const persistedState = localStorage.getItem('reduxState') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reduxState')) : {}
```

and passed the persistedState as an argument when creating my store:

```
const store = createStore(reducer, persistedState);
```

and simply subscribed right after:

```
store.subscribe(()=>{
  localStorage.setItem('reduxState', JSON.stringify(store.getState()))
})
```

Worked like a charm.